# How do I modify the creation of an associated object when done via accepts_nested_attributes_for for another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Job` model, that `belongs_to :company`. Both models `belong_to :user` (i.e. the `current_user`).

`Job accepts_nested_attributes_for :company`.

I have my company attributes on the `jobs/_form.html.erb`.

But, what is happening is that when the company object is being created, it isn't setting an attribute I want it to (`company.user_id`).

I am not quite sure how to force it to do that.

This is what the log for this part of the operation looks like:

```
Company Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "companies" WHERE ("companies"."id" IS NOT NULL) AND "companies"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "phish-me"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (2.7ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" ("name", "logo", "description", "city", "state", "country", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "slug") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Acme Corp"], ["logo", "#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f>"], ["description", "Some random description."], ["city", "Leesburg"], ["state", "Virginia"], ["country", "US"], ["email", "random@email.com"], ["created_at", 2016-06-24 09:50:49 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-06-24 09:50:49 UTC], ["slug", "acme-corp"]]
```

I even tried including a hidden field for the `user_id` in the company portion of that form and it didn't work.

I added a `binding.pry` to my `Company#Create` action and it didn't work - so it seems that's not being called.

I am not quite sure how to modify that Create event and ensure that `company.user = job.user`

How do I do that?

**Edit 1**

My `Jobs#Create`

```
  def create
    @job = current_user.jobs.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        if @job.premium?
          @job.update_columns(price: 200.00)
        end
        format.html { redirect_to job_checkout_path(@job), notice: 'First step complete. Before listing is published, you need to make payment below.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Nothing fancy happening here.

This is my `jobs/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input_field :title %>
  </div>

    # truncated for brevity    

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.association :company, collection: [['New Company', nil]] + current_user.companies.pluck(:name, :id), include_blank: 'Please Select Company', input_html: { id: 'company-select' } %>
  </div>

  <fieldset id='job-fields'>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :company, @job.build_company do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.input :user_id, as: :hidden %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Company Name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input_field :logo, as: :file, placeholder: "Upload company logo." %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input_field :description, as: :text, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter a brief description of the company." %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input_field :city, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter the city (E.g. San Francisco, Cleveland)" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input_field :state, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter the state (E.g. California, Ohio)" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Contact Email Address for the company. This won't be published publicly." %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= ff.input :country, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
  </fieldset>

  <div>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", root_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-outline btn-danger pull-left" %></p>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you add your `create` action and corresponding `view` please?

Comment: @Uzbekjon Which one? My `Jobs#Create`? That's the only thing being hit right now. The question has been updated. Note that I had put a `binding.pry` at the top of my `Company#Create` but it didn't halt the operation so I know that action in that controller is not being hit at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into using merge to add in user_id, which gets a little tricky depending on how your nested attributes and strong params are set up, but in the create action, something like (you would need to inspect the actual post params this is just example):

```
 job_params["company_attributes"].merge!("user_id" => current_user.id)
```

You could also try the merge in your private strong params method for setting job_params...

But the easiest way you could do it is that if Job is getting user_id set properly, then in your Job model, create a callback to set user_id

```
 # app/models/job.rb

 after_create :set_company_user_id

 def set_company_user_id
   self.company.update_column(:user_id, self.user_id)
 end
```

This is assuming your company model has_many :jobs, otherwise if not it might make sense to do this in the company model instead. If you have multiple jobs to a company, it would be more logical to switch this around to make Company accept nested attributes for Job, since there can be more than one to a company.

Comment: I see what you mean re: switching it around. In retrospect, I probably should have done that yes. But I don't want to do that rewrite right now. That's a lot of untangling to do. That being said, The `after_create` callback wouldn't make sense, I don't think, because this would be triggered before the company association has been setup properly and saved, no? I can't do an `update_column` on a record that hasn't been saved/created. I do like the idea, so I very well may try it and see if it works.

Comment: Actually, it turns out you were right first. `after_create` works. Maybe that doesn't get triggered until the entire record and associated records have been setup and saved. It works like a charm now. Thanks for the tip. Change it back, and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: Changed callback to after_create, glad its working for ya